# Add items to nested arrays

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

I use this code to create arrays inside array.

```
array_push($lists, $list);
```

And then I try to add items to nested arrays:

```
array_push($lists[$list], $item);
```

But get an error:

`Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in V:\home\..`.

`$list` is some name, `$item` is an object.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the first parameter is null. Assuming you are using default indexes, you could do something like:

`$numItems = array_push($lists,$list);

array_push($lists[$numItems-1],$item)`

Comment: Any other solution? Two array_push are placed inside different functions and used with foreach. So I can't use $numItems this way.

Comment: If you don't care about indices, you could use: `$list[] = $item;` and then `$lists[] = $list`. But I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish without more information.

Answer (score 1):

This pushes `$list` at the end of `$lists` *and gives it an integer key*:

```
array_push($lists, $list);
```

This tries to access *a string key* into `$lists`, which does not exist:

```
$lists[$list]
```

so the return value is `null`. In the end, it's as if you did

```
array_push(null, $item);
```

For a solution, we need to know if you are doing anything on `$lists` apart from pushing onto it. If you are not, then:

```
$pushed_id = array_push($lists, $list) - 1;
array_push($lists[$pushed_id], $item);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't fix the problem. I have to push $item to $lists[$list]. The question is how to do this in correct way.

Comment: @Rooney: Learn to be polite. **You have not given us the information in the comment to carmstrong's answer, which is essential.** Plus, what you are asking for is not possible **given what we know** *unless* you can pass state from the first function to the other or `$list` has (or can add) a unique id for itself. I apologize for not reading your mind to solve your problem on my own time at no cost to you.